# Cannot start avd emulator on android studio 1.0

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I 've downloaded android studio 1.0 but when I create an emulator and i try to start it gives the following message `PANIC: Could not find android2.ini file in $ANDROID_AVD_HOME nor in $HOME/.android/avd`

Answer (score 13):

### Ubuntu

My .android/avd was in root folder, but setting ANDROID_AVD_HOME to it made no good.
So I just copied files from /root/.android/avd to /home/username/.android/avd
Not best solution, but working

Comment: Same goes for Windows if you changed your user folder from default.

Comment: For those starting android-studio from the terminal, I had this same issue because I started android-studio as sudo. It caused half the files to be in root folders and eventually, this issue.

Comment: This was exactly how i resolved it in ubuntu 14.04 and the reason was i guess using sudo for starting android studio

Answer (score 4):

just set ANDROID_SDK_HOME system variable to point the home directory of android avd, just like you did with JAVA_HOME :)

Comment: but is ANDROID_AVD_HOME what is looking for

Comment: yes, so you need to add it in system variables, if you do that then the path to the avd will be available anywhere.

Comment: I've set ANDROID SDK_HOME like home/user/Android because  inside  this folder its located the SDK folder  but it doesn't work also the message said that it's not in $HOME/.android/avd but the file it's located there.

Comment: inside Android directory there is and SDK directory, include it also in the string path

Comment: well, someone else has had this problem, maybe you'll find something useful here
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78577
Cheers!

Comment: Didn't work either on Windows 8.1. I have set `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`, `$ANDROID_SDK_HOME`, `$ANDROID_AVD_HOME`, `ANDROID_AVD_HOME`. Android Studio 1.1.0. How did Google let such a serious bug slip away?

Comment: You will need to restart Android Studio (and AVD manager) before it can see the new environment variable(s)

Answer (score 3):

1. in the environment variables add  a new "system variables"
   `ANDROID_SDK_HOME=D:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows` (select your home directory of android sdk )
2. modify system variables Path, add "`%Android_SDK_HOME%/tools;`"

it works!

Comment: can confirm this worked for me but it needed an IDE restart before it actually worked.

Answer (score 3):

Test Ubuntu 12.04 & 12.10 & 14.10 & 15.04 & 15.10 & 16.04

Open your terminal (ctrl +t)

```
sudo su
nautilus
```

ctrl + h

Search folder `.android/avd`

Copy this folder `/avd`

Paste in `/home/YouUser/.android/`

And problem solved

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue, and just resolved it by changing the environment variables from `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` to `$ANDROID_AVD_HOME`.

This must have been a change between versions. I had removed all android/appinventor/eclipse programs, SDKs and so on - some manually - in order to get a fresh install and wound up with this error.

Comment: Actually, that's just a bug in your code: ANDROID_AVD_HOME is the name of the environment variable; when you want to reference the value of that variable, then you type $ANDROID_ADV_HOIME. Basic BASH scripting.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete /home/username/.android：
   `$ sudo rm -r .android`
2. Make a link
   `$ sudo ln -s /root/.android ./.android`