# Could not find INI file in $ANDROID_AVD_HOME nor in $HOME/.android/avd

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-tools

I cannot start a virtual devices on android SDK when I press the start button on AVD manager, this error shows on my screen:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus_by_Google'
PANIC: Could not find AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus_by_Google.ini file in
  $ANDROID_AVD_HOME nor in $HOME/.android/avd"!
```

Here is the screen shot:

[image: screen shoot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot start avd emulator on android studio 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494086/cannot-start-avd-emulator-on-android-studio-1-0)

Comment: this resolve my problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/27603135/2652524

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You'll just have to set the ANDROID_AVD_HOME environment variable and restart Android Studio.

Comment: you have to set the ANDROID_AVD_HOME to what? Installation path of android studio?

Comment: Set it to your `Android > AVD` folder. It may be something like `~/.android/avd`.

Comment: I have this env set. Still the same issue!

Answer (score 15):

just this command worked for me :  **sudo cp -R /root/.android $HOME**

Comment: This might work, but will need to do this everyrime you install a new avd. How can one make android stuido to install it in the right place from the beginning?

Answer (score 9):

I solved this problem, on Ubuntu, by finding where the .avd and .ini files from the AVD manager were downloaded. By default, these are named after the virtual device created in the AVD manager and will be like this: `Nexus_4_API_22.ini` and will have a .ini and .avd file both with the same name. In my case, they were located in /root/.android/avd/.

From there, I copied both the ini and avd files of the virtual device (If you have more than one, copy all of the virtual devices you want) into `$HOME/.android/avd/`, as that is one of the locations the message requested. On linux,    `sudo cp /root/.android/avd/Virual_Device_XX.ini $Home/.android/avd/`     and do the same with the .avd file. Hope this helps anyone who runs into this issue.

Comment: I had simillar problem &ndash; needed `armenu.ini` and had `AVD_for_Nexus_4_by_Google.ini armenu.ini`, so solved by: `cd ~/.android/avd && ln -s AVD_for_Nexus_4_by_Google.ini armenu.ini`.

Comment: thanks man this solved my problem.. I was not able to start virtual device on ubuntu 16.04.. just copying /root/.android/avd/Nexus_S_API_28_new.ini to /home/pp/.android/avd worked.. I was not having .android folder on home so created that manually.. Now emulator is finding correct path

Answer (score 6):

For me the Environment variable was missing altogether. 
adding "ANDROID_AVD_HOME" as environment variable solved it.
also a tip, enter the path without the "/.android/avd" part, as the application automatically adds this to it's search you don't need to specify them anymore.
e.g. 
Env. Variable : ANDROID_AVD_HOME
Value : C:\users\%USERNAME%\Androidapps

Android studio will for emulators under C:\users\%USERNAME%\Androidapps.android\avd

Answer (score 5):

Just create a symlink:

```
ln -s /root/.android/ /home/user/.android/
```

This way you will solve the issue with the emulator because all sdk data is being written on /root/.android/

Comment: Bam, this is the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Or instead ANDROID_AVD_HOME enter ANDROID_SDK_HOME and Studio will work: [Cannot start avd emulator on android studio 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494086/cannot-start-avd-emulator-on-android-studio-1-0)

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem again and realized that newer versions of Android Studio and SDK are placing AVDs along the following path for OSX:

Users/yourUsername/Library/Android/sdk/.android/avd as opposed to the older practice of placing AVDs here: Users/yourUsername/.android/avd

So, I just updated my bash_profile file to point ANDROID_AVD_HOME to the new location--which did indeed contain the ini file for the AVD I'd created, and then the launch went fine.

Answer (score 0):

because android SDK environment ANDROID_SDK_HOME, wrong path. /usr/local/opt/android-sdk or /Users/[userName]/Library/Android/sdk TRUE

Comment: I'm not saying this is incorrect, but how is this more useful than the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **ANDROID_SDK_HOME** or **ANDROID_AVD_HOME** is defined correctly and AVD is installed in AVD Manager.

You can get the avd folder path by clicking **view details** of any AVD you have installed.

Directories are searched by emulator in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\avd and $HOME.android\avd .

Check whether the avd folder path matches any of the above path. Make sure there is no empty avd folder in any of the above path of defined environment variables.

Answer (score -4):

Try changing the environment variable definition from `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` to `$ANDROID_AVD_HOME`.

Comment: I think the message is produced by Android Device Manager. I don't think he can easily change it. If its easily changed, then you should probably provide instructions.