# Android studio app running issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Have a look at the image. The circled portion is of my concern. Please tell me a easy solution to this. I am new to android platform.
[image]

Comment: Where are your AVDs located? When you create a new Virtual device (emulator), it is created in a particular folder. Right now, your Android Studio can't find any emulators in the folder you have provided it with.

Comment: I have installed an emulator on a place I know. How can I let android studio know its path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its already answered. Please use the error terms. You just need to set the environment variables $ANDROID_AVD_HOME and others that are said to be missing.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537578/could-not-find-ini-file-in-android-avd-home-nor-in-home-android-avd)! post for more info.