# Suddenly, can't start the Android emulator anymore

Tags: android, android-studio

No matter what I'm doing I'm having this output and the emulator does not start, neither a newly created one. I'm under Windows:

**WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:155:Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\xxxxxxx.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_23.ini for reading.**

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537578/could-not-find-ini-file-in-android-avd-home-nor-in-home-android-avd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting ANDROID_SDK_HOME to a **newly created empty directory**, then creating a new AVD device has helped.

Comment: How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

in file
 projectstructure
  sdklocation

check if the sdk and jdk locations point towards existing locations of an sdk and jdk