# Android ubuntu HOME is defined but could not find .ini file

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

When ever i attempt to start my emulator i get the following message

> PANIC: HOME is defined but could not find test.ini file in
>   $HOME/.android/avd (Note: avd is searched in the order of
>   $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd and
>   $HOME/.android/avd)

And my emulator does not start.

I found a similar question on SO however no answer was selected and the answer are not telling how to fix the issue other than setting `ANDROID_AVD_HOME environment variable`

However im not sure how to do that.

So im hoping one of you guys can help.

im using `android studio on ubuntu 14.04`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494086/cannot-start-avd-emulator-on-android-studio-1-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to run the following command from command line:

```
android avd
```

This will start the **Android Device Manger**, which will list all your configured emulators and their **location** (usually in the form *~/.android/avd*). You can export this location into a system variable called *$ANDROID_AVD_HOME*, and then run the emulator again.

For more info about how to export a variable, take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables).

If you have troubles using the `android` command, your environment may not be set correctly; if this is your case, I suggest you to start from the beginning by following [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/android/#android-dev-env).